# How to implement OAuth Server with GWT

Tags: java, gwt, oauth-2.0

I want to use Google web toolkit to implement OAuth Server.
I searched the question in this forum, but I only found the answer for implement OAuth Client in GWT and Scribe-java.
It's there any possible way to implement OAuth server in GWT with other framework?

Answer (score 1):

GWT is a client-side toolkit, OAuth is an HTTP-based protocol, so all you'll be able to do is the login and/or consent screens; that's mostly outside the scope of OAuth proper actually.

Comment: ops... I mistook GWT as back end. Thx for answering.